# Visualstudio 2012 sharepoint workflow toolbox not visible

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity, visual-studio-2012, farm-solution

I want to create a designer custom action in SharePoint 2013. I use visualstudio 2012 but i can't view SharePoint toolbox . I want to create an activity with createtaskwithcontenttype .

Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this? It sounds like you had the wrong project type open.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the correct project type open.
Try re-creating your project as a "sharepoint workflow project"